# Open population question

Tags: calculus

The following is a model for a pair-formation process in an open population. We denote by $x$ the number of singles in the population and by $y$ the number of pairs, both in thousands. When a pair forms, two singles disappear, and vice versa, when a pair splits up, two singles appear. In addition, singles and pairs immigrate from elsewhere, individuals die, and pairs have offspring, which are of course singles. The system of equations reads

$$dx/dt = −2x+2y+4 
\\
dy/dt = x−3y+2$$

• How many singles and pairs are there at the steady state?

• Draw the nullclines in the phase plane.

• On each nullcline and in each of the four regions in phase space between the nullclines, draw the direction arrows.

• From your direction arrows, tell whether the steady state is stable or not. [Do not use linearization and Jacobian-matrix techniques here.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline, fill in the details.

The critical points $(x' = y' = 0)$, yield a single critical point at $(x, y) = (4,2)$.

The phase portrait, nullclines and direction fields are shown in the following phase portrait (please add all of the details).

[image]

Comment: Did you mean (4,2)?